# Help with sourcing a specific type of integrating sphere

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, reflection, measurements

I am looking for a specific type of integrating sphere that can be used to capture diffuse reflectance measurements, and I would appreciate help with locating a commercially availably version of this sphere. The diagram below illustrates the type of sphere I am looking for [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WPgD.png)]. Two ports are located at equal an opposite angles from the sample normal so that light that is specularly reflected from the sample can be eliminated by a light trap placed in the non-source port.

[image: Integrating sphere for diffuse reflectance measurements.]

I have looked online in attempt to find a commercially available integrating sphere with this design; however, I have only come across general purpose integrating spheres ([such as this Edmund Optics one](https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/general-purpose-integrating-spheres/13160/)) that have ports located directly across or 90 degrees from each other. Any help locating this specific type of integrating sphere would be much appreciated.

1. https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/spectral-reflectance

Comment: This is a question about experimental physics, not engineering. What is it with people voting everything that isn't purely theoretical as engineering?

Answer (score 2):

Our integrating sphere of our Perkin Elmer UV-Vis 950 have this functionality where the spectral reflection could be eliminated from the measurements. I am however not sure if these spheres could be purchased separately.